# Unable to pip install eif on Mac - no module named 'numpy' on install but numpy is installed

Tags: numpy, pip, cython

my windows laptop just died and I pulled the code to run it from my M1 Macbook. I'm horrible with setting environments. I use visual code studio.
I've created a new venv, run pip install numpy, pip install cython and now trying to pip install eif, I am getting the following issue:

```
Collecting eif
  Using cached eif-2.0.2.tar.gz (1.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/firstnamelastname/Documents/Personal/Backup Laptop ROG/AppDataRanking_code/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/firstnamelastname/Documents/Personal/Backup Laptop ROG/AppDataRanking_code/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Users/firstnamelastname/Documents/Personal/Backup Laptop ROG/AppDataRanking_code/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/qv/182dxs7n5db0zwnkzck6zrnc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-t0wjq5jr/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/qv/182dxs7n5db0zwnkzck6zrnc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-t0wjq5jr/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/qv/182dxs7n5db0zwnkzck6zrnc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-t0wjq5jr/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/private/var/folders/qv/182dxs7n5db0zwnkzck6zrnc0000gn/T/pip-build-env-t0wjq5jr/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I am sensing some python variable issue ?
Why would I get a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'" when numpy is clearly installed and working in venv, cf screenshot:

[image showing pip list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqqkC.png)

Thanks in advance

I deleted venv and tried again by just installing 1) numpy 2) Cython 3) eif and it fails at eif.
I tried installing different version of numpy and cython, to no avail. My readings tell me it might be related to cython but I'm not clear.

I tried installed a different package for eif that I remember had worked at the time for my windows 11 which is:
pip install git+https://github.com/dainean/eif.git.

Comment: This mostly happens when you have installed all dependencies at the root without activating your venv. Just check it once.

Comment: It seems I am correctly using "venv" which is my fresh virtual environment, and that the packages are installed there too:
---
(.venv) (base) firstnamelastname@Flos-MacBook-Pro AppDataRanking_code % pip list     
Package    Version
---------- -------
Cython     3.0.2
numpy      1.25.2
pip        23.2.1
setuptools 65.5.0
---